# Why I am not able to bind the interrupts with code LOC, IWI, RES when irqbalance is disabled?

Tags: ubuntu, interrupt, smp

On Ubuntu 14.04, I am trying to bind all the interrupts to core 0 and 1 out of 4 cores. I have disabled the `irqbalance daemon` via file `/etc/init/irqbalance.override`. Then I went to every interrupt in /proc/irq and changed the files `/proc/irq/<irq-num>/smp_affinity_list`. But what I see that interrupts LOC(/etc/init/SERVICE.override), IWI(/etc/init/SERVICE.override) and RES(/etc/init/SERVICE.override) are still being processed on every core, all other interrupts are binded correctly to expected core. Why I am not able to bind these LOC, IWI and RES interrupts? or how to bind them permanently to particular core when `irqbalance` is disabled? Even I have modified file `/proc/irq/default_smp_affinity` to point to core 0 and 1. but no effect.

One more observation. I am not able to bind the cpu list for interrupt 0 and 2. While interrupt 0 seems to be occuring only on cpu 0 and interrupt 2 is not in the file /proc/interrupts and seems to be occurred only for 0 times.